# Json structure with Javascript Mapping

Tags: javascript, html, json, editor

Is any tool or online editor available so that it specify how to access a json element.For example if i provide json as input ,then we should get an output which will specify each item how can we access through javascript

Example

**Assume Input is**

```
    var myList={ "vehicleList": { "Vehicle": [ { "vehicleId": 88, "vehicleName": "veh1", "totalEvents": 10, "medium": 2, "Severe": 2, "Category": [ { "AlertId": 1001, "AlertName": "Overspeed", "Alertcount": 10 }, { "AlertId": 1002, "AlertName": "Sudden acceleration", "Alertcount": 40 } ] }, { "vehicleId": 87, "vehicleName": "veh2", "totalEvents": 11, "medium": 4, "Severe": 7, "Category": [ { "AlertId": 1003, "AlertName": "Overspeed", "Alertcount": 30}, { "AlertId": 1004, "AlertName": "Drunk", "Alertcount": 10 } ] }, { "vehicleId": 87, "vehicleName": "veh3", "totalEvents": 10, "medium": 2, "Severe": 2, "Category": [ { "AlertId": 1007, "AlertName": "Overspeed", "Alertcount": 10 }, { "AlertId": 1008, "AlertName": "Overspeed", "Alertcount": 77 } ] }, { "vehicleId": 86, "vehicleName": "veh4", "totalEvents": 11, "medium": 4, "Severe": 5, "Category": [ { "AlertId": 1009, "AlertName": "Overspeed", "Alertcount": 17 }, { "AlertId": 1010, "AlertName": "HighSpeed", "Alertcount": 10 } ] } ] } };
```

**Output should be** a structure,which will specify like

```
 myList.vehicleList.Vehicle[3].Severe;
```

Comment: Have you tried using firebug? for firefox... It's basically a full HTML/JavaScript debugger.

Comment: even i dont know how to view it in firebug,actually json output is not rendering after enabling firebug.I need a standalone tool

Comment: Ok, so in firebug, open the console tab. Input you json as above. then hit Ctrl+Enter. this will evaluate the javascript in that window

Comment: How to paste the data in firebug console??..."Paste" is not visible inside console tab

Comment: You can also use http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: On the bottom right of the console tab is a little red arrow, click on that to open the editor

Comment: ya..structure is displaying...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you looking backward means providing the value you need what will be the expression to get the value. I don't have a solution for that.

But I would like to suggest json is very easy to read, may be you are having trouble due to long chunk of string. Try this website(editor)  http://jsonlint.com/ this will validate your json and give you in more readable form. Hope this will help you in one or other way.

Comment: i need a javascript expression to access corresponding element,starting from parent element